# Is it possible to have no sorting - to just show results in order of inputted IDs?

Tags: support, feature-request, api-v2.2, sort

I'm trying to send multiple IDs at once (up to a max of 100), but need to use the data in the same order I send the request with.

So, if I send IDs in an arbitary order like `4;1;3;2`, I would like to receive the JSON sorted in the same order, with ID `4`'s info first, then `1`'s, then `3`'s, etc...

Is this possible? Searching around on Stack Apps didn't lead to anything.

If it isn't, would it be worth implementing this as a feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic **"procedural"** (or "row based" or "sequential") **versus "set based"** issue.  See [*Understanding “Set based” and “Procedural” approaches in SQL*](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34142/Understanding-Set-based-and-Procedural-approaches) or any one of thousands of similar articles.

The API uses SQL to get its results and the idea of requiring an *arbitrary* order to results is anathema in SQL -- a sign of possible deficiencies in "set based" thinking.

Because the API uses SQL and because in 99% of cases, an arbitrary-order approach would be suboptimal, I doubt if this feature request will ever get implemented by Stack Exchange.

If you really have one of the cases where an arbitrary order makes real business sense, **please add a concrete example to the question.**
In that case, you will have to reorder the results -- in your desired fashion -- when you display them to the user.

This is not much different than the standard HTTP/AJAX/Packet problem where results can come back in any (unpredictable) order.