# Obtain the list of questions associated to answer_ids without losing the information of which question comes from which answer_id

Tags: support, discussion, questions, answers, limits

[This is a follow up to a previous question of mine,](https://stackapps.com/questions/9226/how-can-i-retrieve-the-reputation-i-or-another-user-fwiw-earned-for-a-given-t) and the starting point is that, given a list of [reputation objects](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/reputation) retrieved via [`/users/{ids}/reputation`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/reputation-on-users), I can easily retain only the entries with `post_type == 'answers'` and then get `post_id` for each of them, ending up with a list of `answer_id`s.

Given this list of `answer_id`s, how can I efficiently obtain the list of [`question` objects](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question) associated to those `answer_id`s ***without*** losing the information of which `question` comes from which `answer_id`?

Clearly, I could make one [`/answers/{ids}/questions`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-answer-ids) request for each of the `answer_id`s, but this means... I'm being kicked out with a `503 (Service unavailable)` (hence the [limits](/questions/tagged/limits) tag).

On the other hand, making one single `/answers/{ids}/questions` request for all the `ids` (well, I should actually make a request for chunks of 100 entries; then maybe I have to browse the few resulting `page`s; but this probably still means a small number of requests), I'm a bit unsure about whether those `question`s are obtained in the same order as the the `answer_id`s. Quite the opposite, from [this answer](https://stackapps.com/a/6295/85941) I understand that there's no guarantee at all that that's the case.

If the retrieved `question`s are not sorted as the `answer_id`s, then the only way I see to re-establish the relation is to make a [`/answers/{ids}`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-by-ids) request as well (again, in chunks of 100 entries, ...), so that I can recognize which `question` corresponds to which `answer_id`, as the `question_id` is both in `question`s and [`answer`s](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/answer).

But this looks a bit a convoluted approach. Plus, retrieving the whole `answer` objects when all I need is the `question_id` for each of them seems overkill.

Is there any other strategy I could adopt? Or is the latter one I described (retrieving all `question`s and all `answer`s from the `answer_id`s) just fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On the other hand, making one single `/answers/{ids}/questions` request for all the `ids` (well, I should actually make a request for chunks of 100 entries; then maybe I have to browse the few resulting `page`s; but this probably still means a small number of requests), I'm a bit unsure about whether those `question`s are obtained in the same order as the the `answer_id`s.

That's the way to go, but make sure you change the filter to one where `answers` is checked; it's off by default:

[image]

That will enable you to find match the questions with the answers you queried for.

Because I love self-referential examples, [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-answer-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=9265&filter=!nKzQUR.HO9&site=stackapps&run=true) is a call which finds the question for this very answer, and you can see the `answer_id` in the result:

[image]

Comment: Oh, so there is a way to get questions with all the answers in it, but not answers with _their one_ question in it. Strange...